# How do I set an environment variable in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have imported an Android project into Android Studio. An environment variable is referenced in the native makefiles of the project, so I need to set this variable within the project.

My question is, how do I set an environment variable in Android studio?

Comment: Android Studio does not use the native makefiles of the project.

Comment: Even the ndk-build component of the build? That sounds broken.

Comment: Android Studio has an `ndk` closure for doing basic NDK builds, with an eye towards replacing makefiles.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to reference an environment variable from `gradle` you can use

```
${System.env.MYVARIABLE}
```

Comment: I'm asking how to define the environment variable within the context of the build session.

Comment: `MYVARIABLE=something studio.sh`